# Fastest way to populate excel worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently working on a excel worksheet with around 300k rows.

For each row i need to fill in a specific cell with a value and depending on some values in that row, i may or may not need to insert new lines. I have a working code to achieve all this but i wonder if there is a faster way to do this?

Currently i am going through every single row and inserting the values at that point. It is taking approximately 7 min to do this.

Is there a way to store all values temporarily and then insert them all at once? wouldn't this be a faster way to do all this?

Thanks

Comment: Yes load the value into an array cycle through the array adding the values to that array or a different array then assign the values back to the range.  If you want more specificity post your working code and request on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ where this question belongs.

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks! But i'm not sure i understood the steps in your comment. could you be a bit more specific please?

Comment: This is not a question for this site.  If you have working code it needs to be on the site linked above.

Comment: @AntónioPires `Range.Value` actually returns a 2d array, assign it to a variable, populate another array processong the first within a `For ... Next` loop, and assign it back to output range.